# Display content from a specific tag only and ignore others

Tags: php, strip-tags

I have a Custom Tag Generator system for XML. I am using custom PHP. Here I am able to add custom XML tags and add its functionality. What I want to achieve is that I would like to show display contents from a specific tag only. Check out the following code if mine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jsaonthego>
  <jobdetails>
    <templateversion>1</templateversion>
    <title>Testing Title</title>
    <taskdetails>Testing Details</taskdetails>
  </jobdetails>
<cem>
    <item>999</item>
</cem>

</jsaonthego>
```

From the above code I would like to show "Testing Title" only but not anything else.

So far I am using the following code without having any luck.

```
<?php
$result = preg_replace('/<jsaonthego<jobdetails<templateversion<taskdetails<cem<item\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\/jsaonthego>item>taskdetails>templateversion>jobdetails>cem>/i', '', $title);
echo $result;
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t mess around with XML with regular expressions; use a proper XML/DOM parser.

Comment: I needed to do as per client requirement.

Comment: I can't believe something's willing to pay money to specifically parse XML avoiding XML parsers. Is it a school assignment to complement a regular expressions lesson? There's nothing wrong with that but we need actual context to properly answer questions.

Comment: BTW, the reason why your regexp doesn't work is that you're basically making up the syntax: `<jsaonthego<jobdetails<templateversion`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP has several builtin [XML libraries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php). For this use case I would opt for [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php):

```
$jsaonthego = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $jsaonthego->jobdetails->title;
```

([demo](https://3v4l.org/36VAR))